# VBA XML Authentication & Screen Scraping a webpage to excel

Tags: xml, vba, excel, authentication

I’m attempting to make this VBA XML script work on a website that requires authentication but I don’t have the authentication part of the process right yet to work & I need assistance please.

XML code below seems to run OK, it copies most records & paste into excel sheet but the output is missing actual Birth Dates info & actual Birth Place info.

Here is the code so far, which works to copy the data table records:

'My sincere thanks and appreciation to @SIM for his input into parts of the code below.

```
Private Function Escape(ByVal URL As String) As String

    Dim i As Integer, BadChars As String
    BadChars = "<>%=&!@#£$^()+{[}]|\;:'"",/?"

    For i = 1 To Len(BadChars)

        URL = Replace(URL, Mid(BadChars, i, 1), "%" & Hex(Asc(Mid(BadChars, i, 1))))
    Next i

    URL = Replace(URL, " ", "+")
    Escape = URL

End Function

Sub GetDataWithXmlSearch()  

    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument, HTMLdoc2 As HTMLDocument
    Dim URL As String
    Dim username As String, password As String
    Dim HTTP As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim posts As Object
    Dim elem As Object
    Dim trow As Object
    Dim QuerySP$
    Dim LINK$
    Dim i&
    Dim c As Long 
    Dim r As Long 

    username = "myusername"
    password = "mypassword"
    URL = "https://www.ancestry.com.au/secure/login
    Set HTMLdoc2 = New HTMLDocument
    Set HTMLdoc = HTMLdoc2.createDocumentFromUrl(URL, "")

    While HTMLdoc.ReadyState <> "complete": DoEvents: Wend

    LINK = "https://search.ancestry.com.au/cgi-bin/sse.dll?" 'thanks SIM

    For i = 50 To 15000 Step 50   

        QuerySP = "_phsrc=xNG92&_phstart=successSource&usePUBJs=true&db=FS1ScotlandBirthsandBaptisms&gss=angs-d&new=1&rank=1&msbdy=1900&msbdy_x=1&msbdp=10&MSAV=1&uidh=000&gl=&gst=&hc=50&fh=11500&fsk=BEIgT4gIgADq7wAvWKY-61-&fh=" & i & ""

        With HTTP
            .Open "GET", LINK & QuerySP, False
            .send
            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        Set posts = html.getElementById("results-main").getElementsByTagName("table")(0)

        For Each elem In posts.Rows
            For Each trow In elem.Cells
                c = c + 1: Cells(r + 1, c) = trow.innerText
            Next trow
            c = 0: r = r + 1
        Next elem

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: If it copies most information what makes you think the problem is with authentication rather than extracting all the required information?

Comment: If its only two fields then you can try using `Regex` or `String functions` to parse `actual Birth Dates info & actual Birth Place info` from `.responseText`

Comment: I don't know guys that's why I'm seeking help please.